# How to change the build dependencies of a Debian source package?

Tags: deb, dpkg

I am trying to work with OpenIMS.
you can find a walk-through of it in [here](http://www.openimscore.org/debian_packages)

when trying to build packages for `openimscore_fhoss`, using this piece of command:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
```

it fails to build packages and says:

> dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: sun-java6-jdk
>   dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied;
>   aborting

I have openjdk and openjre already installed.
is there any way to make dpkg, depend on openjdk instead of sun-java6-jdk ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the `debian/control` file, specifically the Build Dependencies section. Remember to be sure that the build dependencies are about a specific package instead a virtual/meta package. This is to have an assurance that things will workout.